# Mocking a simple function in VueJS, JEST

Tags: javascript, vue.js, unit-testing, jestjs, vue-component

I am struggling to mock the delete function in the lists component.

My test looks like this at the moment

```
  describe("delete a todo", () => {
    test("should have todo removed", async () => {
      const deleteItem = jest.fn();
      const items = [{ id: 1, name: "ana", isComplete: false }];
      const wrapper = shallowMount(Todo, items);
      console.log(wrapper);
      const deleteButton = ".delete";
      wrapper.find(deleteButton).trigger("click");
      expect(deleteItem).toHaveBeenCalledWith("1");
    });
```

currently, when I run the tests the error reads.
[Test Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IZcAC.jpg)

The application works fine, but I am not mocking the delete function correctly in my test as a "New Note" is still being passed through. What am I doing wrong?

just in case it helps, here is a part of the file I am testing.

```
methods: {
    addItem() {
      if (this.newItem.trim() != "") {
        this.items.unshift({
          // id: createUID(10),
          id: uuid.v4(),
          completed: false,
          name: this.newItem
        });
        this.newItem = "";
        localStorage.setItem("list", JSON.stringify(this.items));
        this.itemsLeft = this.itemsFiltered.length;
      }
    },
    removeItem(item) {
      const itemIndex = this.items.indexOf(item);
      this.items.splice(itemIndex, 1);
      localStorage.setItem("list", JSON.stringify(this.items));
      this.itemsLeft = this.itemsFiltered.length;
    },
```

Also for more code, you can get it from the following link :
https://github.com/oliseulean/ToDoApp-VueJS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have to make some changes to your original test case

1. Change jest.fn() to jest.spyOn(Todo.methods, 'deleteItem') since you have to track calls to methods object in Todo component. Refer: https://jestjs.io/docs/jest-object
2. Wait for the click event to be triggered with await
3. Use toHaveBeenCalledTimes not toHaveBeenCalledWith("1")

So your final test case will look like this

```
describe("delete a todo", () => {
    test("should have todo removed", async () => {
      const removeItem = jest.spyOn(Todo.methods, 'removeItem')
      const items = [{ id: 1, name: "ana", isComplete: false }];
      const wrapper = shallowMount(Todo, items)
      await wrapper.find('.delete').trigger('click')
      expect(removeItem).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    });
});
```

Comment: I still get the error.
You can see the error in the image: https://ibb.co/qRt9M62

Comment: Sorry, my bad. You should give the function name that you are going to test into spyOn method ("removeItem"). I have updated the script accordingly. Can you check now?